# how to use 'select' for this job

Tags: sql, sqlite, select

i have a table in sqlite database like following.

```
    id    status

    =============
    x     0
    y     1
    y     0
    x     1
    x     1 
    z     0
```

As the example, i have 3 different id with status(0/1), and x was found 3 times in the table, with status=0 for 1 time, status=1 for 2 times, y was found 2 times in the table, with status=0 for 1 time and status=1 for 1 time.

so, i want to use 'select' to get the following result, is there any way to do this job? any help would be appreciated. thanks

```
    id     sum(status=0)     sum(status=1)   total(status)
    ========================================================
    x      1                  2              3
    y      1                  1              2
    z      1                  0              1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this should work:

```
SELECT id, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN status = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS SUM_STATUS_0, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN status = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS SUM_STATUS_1,
    SUM(status) AS SUM_STATUS
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY id
```

Answer (score 0):

This should also work as null values are not counted by `count`:

```
select id,
  count(case when status = 0 then 1 end) Status0,
  count(case when status = 1 then 1 end) Status1,
  count(*) StatusAll
from t
group by id
```